# how to rotate a texture along a bezier curve

Tags: texturing, bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

i have a bezier curve. i used geometry nodes to add an object as it's spline. then i created a material which has a wave texture. i was able to use a capture attribute and send that data to the material in order for the wave texture to follow the curve (by watching a default cube tutorial). but what i am trying to do is rotate the texture 90 degrees.

[image: current]

[image: red lines indicate rotation]

geometry node setup
[image]

which passes the capture attribute as "coord"
[image]

and sends it to the material.

shader node setup:
[image]

Comment: Switch the Wave texture from X to Y ? Or.. take the captured vector parameter, and switch the X and Y components using  _Separate XYZ_ and _Combine XYZ_ Nodes

Comment: neither one seemed to work. i feel like i am supposed to take the wave texture and use that to create a new wave texture that is perpendicular to the first one, and then delete or mask the first one. i dunno.

Comment: @mark what about adding a mapping node with a texture coordinate into the wave texture vector and changing it to 90 degrees? This might not work since I specifically don't know what is your material/geometry nodes etup.

Comment: Need to see how you're doing this.. all trees..

Comment: i edited my post to include my node setups

Comment: did you try to connect the resample curve output to the capture attribute input? (tbh i have no idea what your "plane" is...)

Answer (score 0):

You should capture attribute from another curve:

[image]

> why? can you elaborate?

capture attribute takes information from one point of the node tree and transfer it to the other. Let's take a look at example:

Here you can see a sphere and cube intersecting each other:

[image]

Now let's delete cube from the intersection. To get cube faces, we use capture attribute, and mark all cube faces by true:

[image]

If we put capture attribute in sphere branch, we delete sphere faces:

[image]

Same for your example. Then you put capture attribute from one line, you will get its own spline factor.

Comment: why? can you elaborate?

Comment: i'm still curious....